# Subtracting rows and columns from a vector at non-zero indices MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

Suppose I have the following matrix in MATLAB:

```
A =[0    0    4    0; 
    0    5    0    3; 
    1    2    0    0];
```

given the following vectors:

```
b1 = [1 2 3];
b2 = [2 3 4 5];
```

the output should look like this:

```
C1 =[0    0    3    0; 
     0    3    0    1; 
    -2   -1    0    0];

C2 =[0    0    0    0; 
     0    2    0   -2; 
    -2   -1    0    0];
```

C1 and C2 are column-wise and row-wise subtraction of the original matrix A from vectors happening at **non-zero elements**. Note A in reality is **sparse matrix**. Obviously answers without using loop is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one might be a little more memory efficient:

```
A =[0    0    4    0; 
    0    5    0    3; 
    1    2    0    0];

b1 = [1 2 3].';   % transpose so it's a column vector
b2 = [2 3 4 5].';

[Arows Acols Avals] = find(A);
C1 = sparse([Arows;Arows], [Acols;Acols], [Avals;-b1(Arows)]);
C2 = sparse([Arows;Arows], [Acols;Acols], [Avals;-b2(Acols)]);
```

Results:

```
>> full(C1)
ans =

   0   0   3   0
   0   3   0   1
  -2  -1   0   0

>> full(C2)
ans =

   0   0   0   0
   0   2   0  -2
  -1  -1   0   0
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `sparse` adds the values given for duplicate subscripts. `A` can be sparse or full.

Comment: Your solution is exactly what i was looking for. So, in essence your solution and Tony's provide the same result but yours focuses on non-zero elements of the sparse matrix rather Tony's on zero-elements. I admit that I did not not mention in my original question the size of my matrix, it was my mistake, but the fact that I mentioned I am looking for the solution to work for sparse matrices, it can be indicative of the fact that my matrix contains many zeros (more zeros than nonzeros). Therefore, for such matrices your solution is more efficient. Thanks everybody for your consideration.

Comment: Exactly, this only generates as many values from the vectors `b1` and `b2` as there are nonzero elements in `A`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a loop. First perform the subtractions and then replace the elements that should remain `0`.

```
C1 = A - repmat(b1.',1,size(A,2));
C2 = A - repmat(b2,size(A,1),1);
C1(A==0)=0;
C2(A==0)=0;

C1 =

     0     0     3     0
     0     3     0     1
    -2    -1     0     0

C2 =

     0     0     0     0
     0     2     0    -2
    -1    -1     0     0
```

**Test on Sparse Matrix**

You can also confirm that this will work on Sparse Matirces

```
A = sparse(10,10);
A(5:6,5:6)=rand(2);
b1 = rand(10,1);
b2 = rand(1,10);

B1 = A - repmat(b1,1,size(A,2));
B2 = A - repmat(b2,size(A,1),1);

B1(A==0)=0;
B2(A==0)=0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, do you know if they work for sparse matrices as well?

Comment: Your solution works very well for small matrices. In my case, for a big matrix I recieve this error: `Error using  == 
Requested 4658367597x1 (34.7GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater
than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or
preference panel for more information.

Error in demo_main (line 50)
    B1(A==0)=0;`

I have to think of a way to replace `A==0`, any ideas?

Comment: @YAS my answer addresses your specific question properly. But you are just pivoting around and changing it. If your problem is regarding big data, then you should mention it in another question. comment is not a good place to ask a totally different question.

Comment: @YAS in addition you can see clearly the error msg `array exceeds maximum array size preference` is not because of the method but the memory limitation.

Comment: The only think I did not mention was the fact that my original matrix can be big. I have couple of my original matrix A in place, I used your solution and it worked well for matrices with certain limited size, but not for big ones. In this case, A is of size 76K*65K.

Answer (score 0):

```
C1 = A ~= 0; // save none zero elements of A
b1 = b1.';   // transpose b1
b1 = [b1, b1, b1, b1];  // create matrix of same size as A
C1 = C1.*b1;            
C1 = A-C1;
```

**C1:**

```
 0     0     3     0
 0     3     0     1
-2    -1     0     0
```

Next is C2

```
 C2 = A ~= 0;
 k = [b2; b2; b2];
 C2 = C2.*k;
 C2 = A-C2;
```

**C2:**

```
 0     0     0     0
 0     2     0    -2
-1    -1     0     0
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Your solution also works but I prefer to avoid matrix arithmetic operations to as much as possible as I am dealing with rather big matrices. Can you help to answer my latest comment under NKN.